# Unplayable turn in Beethoven sonata

Tags: piano, notation, ornaments, beethoven

Beethoven's piano sonata Op. 2 No. 3, first movement,
bars 179-180 (Henle edition).
[image: Beethoven Op 2 No 3 bars 179-180]

The turn decorating each eighth note can be played literally.
Except for the one on bar 179's A sharp, because there's
no good candidate for that turn's lower auxiliary note.
G natural is too low.  G sharp is harmonically bogus.  G double sharp is Chopin, not Beethoven.

So should the B - A sharp with turn be instead simplified into
a B with turn, where A sharp is the lower auxiliary?

Should the dozen similar instances also be simplified thus?

I prefer arguments stronger than so-and-so recorded it like such-and-such.

**Edit:** A turn with a tiny sharp underneath occurs in bar 27 and in bar 161, both in the Henle and in the first edition (p. 32 bottom, p. 36 middle; although here the sharp is above, not underneath).
Had Beethoven wanted the Casella interpretation, he would have notated
it that way too: a quarter note B with a turn plus sharp.
So we can't explain the Casella as a modernization of an archaic spelling.

Comment: Hehe... "G double sharp is Chopin, not Beethoven" made me smile. :-)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Beethoven goofed.  It's up to individual taste whether to play Casella's triplets or literal turns.  But at a fast enough tempo and with some pedal, the unbeethovenian G double sharp can be tolerably overlooked in the resulting flurry.

Comment: I'm letting this answer stand, merely to see how many downvotes it accumulates. The absence of comments suggests that the reason is nothing more than insulting Ludwig Van.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the first edition: http://conquest.imslp.info/files/imglnks/usimg/b/b1/IMSLP51972-PMLP01414-Beethoven_-_Piano_Sonata_No.3_(Artaria).pdf

[image: Beethoven Op2 n3 mvtI m179]

Inverted symbol but of course it's not an inverted turn.

Now take a look at edition Casella 1919 http://conquest.imslp.info/files/imglnks/usimg/8/81/IMSLP68708-PMLP01414-Opus_2_no_3.pdf
The figure is to be played as noted here.[image: Beethoven Op2 n3 mvtI m179 edition Casella 1919]

Comment: Camille it’s probably Beethoven’s shorthand for what Casella has notated.

Comment: Why would Casella be a credible source? In 1919 Beethoven was long dead and HIP hadn’t been invented, leading to a lot of truly horrible editions. Why is Casella an exception? Additionally, the turn on the lower note being a shorthand is absolute nonsense since you get exactly what Casella notates if you turn the first of each four eighth note group into a quarter and put the turn on the second half which would be just as short (or arguably shorter) yet not ambiguous.

Comment: (For some readers: HIP means https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historically_informed_performance)

Comment: At first glance, to my ears I hear of what is in Henle and the 1st ed. as what you have described, quarter turn, eighth eighth. The chromatically altered lower neighbor has the turn symbol; the short hand we use today is a small accidental under the turn symbol. Next time I'm at the Beethoven Center I'll have to enquire about the figure.

Comment: This is fascinating. I don’t know anything about the believability of Casella, but it’s intriguing that their version *does* create a textbook example of a turn, but it’s a turn ornamenting the first note rather than the second. It doesn’t seem like a completely implausible interpretation, but I agree that I’d want more documentation.

Comment: the editions are the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Shai Wosner takes the turns as given by Casella. But Paavali Jumppanen treats each turn as if the note it's with is the turn's principal note. He plays G double sharp.